# how to compile multiple c files using makefile in Linux - getting variable errors

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to compile 5 `*.c` files using `Makefile` (`gcc -o prog add.c create.c delete.c display.c main.c`) but I am getting `variable is not declared` errors. I created putting `main.c` first in the command above but still same error. 
Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here and how can I make variable so it can be read by complier?

Again below code is divided into 5 files
Error:

```
add.c: In function ‘add’:
add.c:3:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t*****ADD Menu*****");
  ^~~~~~
add.c:3:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
add.c:3:2: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
add.c:5:6: error: ‘left’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  if (left == SIZE - 1)
      ^~~~
add.c:5:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
add.c:5:14: error: ‘SIZE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  if (left == SIZE - 1)
              ^~~~
add.c:12:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘scanf_s’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   scanf_s("%d", &holder);
   ^~~~~~~
add.c:15:3: error: ‘numarr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   numarr[left] = holder;
   ^~~~~~
add.c:16:7: error: ‘right’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   if (right == -1)
       ^~~~~
create.c: In function ‘create’:
create.c:3:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tArray has been created with the size of 10 elements");
  ^~~~~~
create.c:3:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
create.c:3:2: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
delete.c: In function ‘delete’:
delete.c:4:6: error: ‘right’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  if (right == -1)
      ^~~~~
delete.c:4:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
delete.c:6:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tERROR! Queue is empty. Please add element before deleting them");
   ^~~~~~
delete.c:6:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
delete.c:6:3: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
delete.c:10:12: error: ‘numarr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   holder = numarr[right];
            ^~~~~~
delete.c:11:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
   printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tSUCCESS. Deleted item: %d", holder);
   ^~~~~~
delete.c:11:3: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
delete.c:13:15: error: ‘left’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  if (right == left)
               ^~~~
display.c: In function ‘display’:
display.c:4:6: error: ‘right’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  if (right == -1)
      ^~~~~
display.c:4:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
display.c:6:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tEmter elements to array to be displayed here!");
   ^~~~~~
display.c:6:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
display.c:6:3: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
display.c:10:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
   printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tDisplay of current elements in queue: ");
   ^~~~~~
display.c:10:3: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
display.c:11:24: error: ‘left’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   for (i = right; i <= left; i++)
                        ^~~~
display.c:12:29: error: ‘numarr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t%d", numarr[i]);
                             ^~~~~~
main.c:3:10: fatal error: conio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <conio.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #define SIZE 10
    int numarr[SIZE];
    int right, left;

    //function create is in separate c file named create.c
    void create()
    {
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tArray has been created with the size of 10 elements");
    }

    //function add is in separate c file named add.c
    void add()
    {
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t*****ADD Menu*****");
        int holder;
        if (left == SIZE - 1)
        {
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tQueue is FULL");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter the element you wish to add into queue: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &holder);
            ++left;

            numarr[left] = holder;
            if (right == -1)
                right = 0;
        }
    }

    //function delete is in separate c file delete.c
    void delete()
    {
        int holder;
        if (right == -1)
        {
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tERROR! Queue is empty. Please add element before deleting them");
        }
        else
        {
            holder = numarr[right];
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tSUCCESS. Deleted item: %d", holder);
        }
        if (right == left)
        {
            right = left = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            right++;
        }
    }

    //function display is in separate c file named display.c
    void display()
    {
        int i;
        if (right == -1)
        {
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tEmter elements to array to be displayed here!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tDisplay of current elements in queue: ");
            for (i = right; i <= left; i++)
                printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t%d", numarr[i]);
        }
    }

    //function main is in separate c file named main.c
    int main()
    {
        right = left = -1;
        int choice;
        do
        {
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tWELCOME TO C PROGRAM ON FIFO \n");
            printf("\t\t\t\t1. CREATE an array \n");
            printf("\t\t\t\t2. ADD to array \n");
            printf("\t\t\t\t3. DELETE from arra \n");
            printf("\t\t\t\t4. DISPLAY the array's content \n");
            printf("\t\t\t\t5. EXIT the program \n");
            printf("\t\t\t\tPlease SELECT from above options: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &choice);
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                //create
                create();
            break;

            case 2:
                //add
                system("cls");
                add();
                break;

            case 3:
                //delete
                delete();
                break;

            case 4:
                //display
                display();
                break;

            case 5:
                exit(0);
            }
        } while (choice != 5);

        return 0;
    }``
```

Comment: `gcc a.c b.c c.c` compiles three separate files independently of each other; it doesn't somehow concatenate them together as I think you are thinking they might. You have to declare everything in each file, or use a common header to share declarations, etc, between them.

Comment: Your question contains nothing related to make, gnumake, or a makefile. Please revise the question, remove the inappropriate tags and update the title. This helps **you** to get the best answer. The same applies to the tags `linux`, `ubuntu-18.04` since the described problem is only related to the use of GNU C compiler. The intention of the tags is to focus on a topic, not to describe your working environment.

Comment: You keep forgetting to `#include <stdio.h>` — that's what one error for `add.c`, `create.c`, `delete.c` and `display.c` says.  If you can't find `<conio.h>`, you either aren't on Windows or don't have the correct legacy libraries installed.  Since the question is tagged with Ubuntu, you need to port the code from Windows to Unix — meaning finding a surrogate `<conio.h>` and library, or revising the code not to need it.  Note that the Curses library does provide a `getch()` function, but you have to do setup work before you can use it, and clean up afterwards too.

Answer (score 1):

You are developing a program that you have split into several "modules". Each module is a .c file.

When you compile all these modules, the compiler generates a .o file for each .c file *without knowing they are related*. Each compilation is called a "compilation unit".

To "tell" the compiler the source files are related, you create .h files that you can `#include` in your .c files and that contain the information about the other modules that each .c file needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually asking both about `Makefile` and the process of compilation.

`Makefile` file contains rules with the following structure:

```
output: input1 input2
   command_to_obtain_output_from_inputs
```

Check [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compiling-a-c-program-behind-the-scenes/) to see how compilation works. You will see the different step: preprocessing (i.e. replacing macros) compilation, assembly (generate machine code from your file but not substituting the commands from external libraries), linking (putting your machine code together with the machine code of external libraries to have your final executables).

The file will be read from the beginning until a first rule is found defining the final output of the process.

Starting from the end the executable is the result of linking process which needs the `*.o` files.
In the `Makefile` this must be your first rule (above all the others) that generally is something like.

executable: o1.o o2.o
    gcc $^ -o $@

where `$@` is the filename of the target of the rule, `executable` in this case and `$@` are all the inputs `o1.0`, `o2.o`.

Since `make` at least the first time will not find those files it continues scanning the `Makefile` to find another rule to create them (the `*.o` files).
Such rule can be something like:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c Makefile 
    gcc -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

and it will be the rule valid to create all the `*.o` needed.

where `$<` is the first prerequisite i.e. the corresponding `%.c` file. Also the `Makefile` has been added as dependency to regenerate the `*.o` in case it is changed but it is not used in the command. `-MMD` will create `*.d` files for dependencies but generally it is not needed.

`Makefile` also allows you to define variables so that you cane refer them through all your file. Just to give you an example I will post a `Makefile` of mine.

```
CXX = gcc

SOURCEDIR := ./
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIR=$(SOURCEDIR)/obj
LIBS = ... #your external libraries
CXXFLAGS = ... #your flags
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))

# ADD MORE WARNINGS!
WARNING := -Wall -Wextra

# .PHONY means these rules get executed even if
# files of those names exist.
.PHONY: all clean

# The first rule is the default, ie. "make",
# "make all" and "make parking" mean the same
all: ruptime

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) ruptime

# Linking the executable from the object files
# $^   # "src.c src.h" (all prerequisites)
ruptime: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC_PATH) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)

-include $(DEPENDS)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
#Note the dependency from the folder $(OBJDIR) and the
#rule above to generate it. However with the symbol |
# no ricompilation is perform if the folder if it modified
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how I do it,

Suppose there are 5 .c files

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 10

int right,left;
int numarr[SIZE];
extern void create();
extern void add();
extern void delete();
extern void display();
int main()
{
    right = left = -1;
    int choice;
    do
    {
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tWELCOME TO C PROGRAM ON FIFO \n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t1. CREATE an array \n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t2. ADD to array \n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t3. DELETE from arra \n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t4. DISPLAY the array's content \n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t5. EXIT the program \n");
        printf("\t\t\t\tPlease SELECT from above options: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            //create
            create();
        break;

        case 2:
            //add
            system("cls");
            add();
            break;

        case 3:
            //delete
            delete();
            break;

        case 4:
            //display
            display();
            break;

        case 5:
            exit(0);
        }
    } while (choice != 5);

    return 0;
}
```

**delete.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
extern int right,left,numarr[SIZE];
//function delete is in separate c file delete.c
void delete()
{
    int holder;
    if (right == -1)
    {
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tERROR! Queue is empty. Please add element before deleting them");
    }
    else
    {
        holder = numarr[right];
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tSUCCESS. Deleted item: %d", holder);
    }
    if (right == left)
    {
        right = left = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        right++;
    }
}
```

**display.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
extern int right,left,numarr[SIZE];
//function display is in separate c file named display.c
 void display()
 {
     int i;
     if (right == -1)
     {
         printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tEmter elements to array to be displayed here!");
     }
     else
     {
         printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tDisplay of current elements in queue: ");
         for (i = right; i <= left; i++)
             printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t%d", numarr[i]);
     }
 }
```

**create.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>

//function create is in separate c file named create.c
void create()
{
  printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tArray has been created with the size of 10 elements");
}
```

**add.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
//function add is in separate c file named add.c
extern int left,right;
extern int numarr[SIZE];
void add()
{
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t*****ADD Menu*****");
    int holder;
    if (left == SIZE - 1)
    {
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tQueue is FULL");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter the element you wish to add into queue: ");
        scanf("%d", &holder);
        ++left;

        numarr[left] = holder;
        if (right == -1)
            right = 0;
    }
}
```

compile each .c files into their respective object files and link them together.

**makefile**

```
compile :
    gcc -c main.c -o main.o
    gcc -c create.c -o create.o
    gcc -c add.c -o add.o
    gcc -c delete.c -o delete.o
    gcc -c display.c -o display.o
    gcc main.o create.o add.o delete.o display.o -o file.o
```

on the ternimal type

> $ make compile

Notice how I used extern keyword for the functions as well as for the shared variables.

It works like this:
During compilation the compiler sees an identifier/symbol being used which is not defined in the current file. The extern keyword tells the compiler that this symbol has been defined somewhere else.
Finally during the process of linking this symbol reference is resolved by the linker.

Answer (score 0):

Above program works now after I made following changes as per answers and suggestions from here:
-Created fundec.h file and added into all .c files.
-Changed scanf_s to scanf
-Added #include  to all files
-Removed #include

fundec.h contains

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Global variables
#define SIZE 10
int numarr[SIZE];
int right, left;

//Declaration of functions
void create();
void add();
void delete();
void display();
```